# Find a second root of $x^3+px+q$ given the first root

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field, cubics

This is a problem from Artin where given one root $a$, you have to find an equation for a second root in terms of $a$, $p$, $q$, and the square root of the discriminant $\delta$.

Here's what I have so far.
The coefficients are the symmetric functions evaluated at the roots, so if the roots are $a$,$b$,$c$ then:

$s_1=a+b+c=0$

$s_2=ab+ac+bc=p$

$s_3=abc=-q$

And we can also use the square root of the discriminant,

$(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)=\delta=\sqrt{-p^3-27q^2}$

At this point it looks like its just doing a bunch of algebra to cancel $c$ and write $b$ in terms of $a,p,q,\delta$ but I've been at it for a while and don't seem to be having any luck.

Comment: You can use polynomial long division and divide by (x-a), which leaves a quadratic equation.

Comment: There is really no reason to provide the discriminate, unless it is a perfect square. Is the square root of the discriminant specified rational? Because in that case the field extension generated by any one of the roots is the root field. The other two roots would be in this field, and they can be expressed as  linear combinations of 1, the original root, and the square of this root.

Comment: I've already solved it and what you say is true - you can express the other roots only in terms of p,q,a but the expression includes the square root of some elements, which you can get rid of by rewriting it in terms of $\delta$. My guess is they give you $\delta$ because it has a "nicer" form if you only have to use the root of the discriminant rather than any other roots (even if the discriminant isn't a square either)

Answer (score 4):

We have $b+c = -a$ and $bc=-\frac{q}a$. This means $b$ and $c$ are roots of the quadratic
$$y^2+ay-\frac{q}a = 0 \implies ay^2 + a^2y - q = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps less elegant approach is to perform division.  Then,

$$\frac{x^3+px+q}{x-a}=x^2+ax+(a^2+p)+\frac{q+a(a^2+p)}{x^3+px+q}$$

Thus since $a$ is a root, we can eliminate $q$ as $q=-a(a^2+p)$.

Find the other roots, from the  quadratic factor, in terms of $a$ and $p$.